# Making WPF user control mark click events as handled

Tags: wpf, user-controls, click, routedevents

I have a custom controls which propagates the mouse click event up the visual tree and I would like to get rid of this behaviour. Is there a way to mark a routed event (which was raised by button click or other mouse event) as handled from xaml in my UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `e.Handled = true;` to try and swallow events. Although button click events shouldn't bubble.